# Facebook OG won't retrieve my picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have one project and have a real problem. Since i have connected 3 social networks all of them works fine and share picture very good but Facebook don't.

It's just don't show my picture and i really frustrated on what actually should i do.

Here is the link.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Femojimaps.simcoeapp.ru%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D95

So problem is only in that it doesn't show the picture i create and what it says that it couldn't load the image. But my server supports gzip and Deflate

Will be happy for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Correct your `og:url` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is encodeURIComponent() modified url - is correct!